# Alternative to Glenair Surface Mount Right Angle Printed Circuit Board Connectors

Tags: connector

We have been using [MWDM1L-31SSMRNT](https://cdn.glenair.com/micro-d/pdf/c/mwdm-smr.pdf) from Glenair (image attached)

These are **right angle solder mount** micro d-sub connectors with 31 pins.

We are trying to see if we can find cheaper and more readily available alternatives.

Could someone point us in the right direction? I have been searching around to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Gender: Male? Female?

Comment: how many pins do you require? ... what kinds of signals are involved?

Comment: @DavideAndrea  socket connectors

Comment: @jsotola 31 pins. just basic DC signals...

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=mezzanine+connector&iax=images&ia=images

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Airborn makes them too: https://www.digikey.com/short/04bhp5pn

VERY expensive!

You'd be better off redesigning the board to use a different connector.

Comment: ITT cannon is the other alternative.